# Magento soap api to get the updated oders

Tags: magento-1.9, api, soap

Can anyone help me how to fetch the updated orders in magento1.9 using soap api.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is for SOAP v2:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:urn="urn:Magento" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <urn:salesOrderList soapenv:encodingStyle="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/">
         <sessionId xsi:type="xsd:string">your-session-id-here</sessionId>
         <filters xsi:type="urn:filters">
            <complex_filter>
              <complexFilterArray>
                <key>updated_at</key>
                <value>
                  <key>gt</key>
                  <value>2018-09-19 00:00:00</value>
                </value>
              </complexFilterArray>
            </complex_filter>
         </filters>
      </urn:salesOrderList>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The above will fetch orders having `updated_at` value greater than `2018-09-19 00:00:00`.